# losing content when sending ajax value to php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Im using ajax to send data to php and the following is whats being sent

> title=2&note= Logo mynameisdonald%s's Photo mynameisdonald Sign Out
>   Forums Garage Club Shop Classifieds Systems My-STOC Club Advanced This
>   forum Fiesta ST Owners Club → Fiesta ST Mk6 Technical Handbook →
>   Brakes, Wheels & Tyres View New Content Shoutbox Open the Shoutbox in
>   a popup We've noticed that you've been inactive for over 10 minute(s).
>   We've stopped running the Shoutbox due to your inactivity. If you are
>   back again, please click the I'm Back button below. 3 Follow this
>   forum Brakes, Wheels & Tyres Page 1 of 172 1 2 3 Next » Start New
>   Topic Mark this forum as read Recently Updated Start Date Most Replies
>   Most Viewed Custom New Replies Pinned center caps Started by Jim, 22
>   Jun 2006 1 2 3 13 → Hot 190 replies 5,979 views center caps - last
>   post by ST-Lloydy ST-Lloydy 13 Feb 2013 Pinned Centre Caps Fitting
>   Diagram Started by Scotty H , 20 Mar 2009 6 replies 993 views Centre
>   Caps Fitting Diagram - last post by Toby Toby 01 Nov 2010 New Replies
>   Brakes Started by I9 Conrad 9I, 27 Jan 2013 1 2 3 6 → Hot 84 replies
>   907 views Brakes - last post by JackJack JackJack 15 minutes ago You
>   posted in this topic Brake pad change - Stiff hubs Started by
>   matt_t586, Yesterday, 23:04 4 replies 25 views Brake pad change -
>   Stiff hubs - last post by matt_t586 matt_t586 Today, 10:01 You posted
>   in this topic ST Caliper Seals Started by mynameisdonald, Today, 09:54
>   0 replies 2 views ST Caliper Seals - last post by mynameisdonald
>   mynameisdonald Today, 09:54 New Replies Uneven brake pad wear Started
>   by TTC, Yesterday, 19:09 9 replies 55 views Uneven brake pad wear -
>   last post by JackJack JackJack Yesterday, 21:07 New Replies Uniroyal
>   rainsport 2's Started by teeman, 15 Feb 2013 1 2 16 replies 116 views
>   Uniroyal rainsport 2's - last post by sme101 sme101 Yesterday, 13:06
>   What Centre Cap Fits the Middle of the ST's Wheels. Started by
>   Suicida1 Zombie, 04 Feb 2013 9 replies 87 views What Centre Cap Fits
>   the Middle of the ST's Wheels. - last post by Alec M Alec M Yesterday,
>   10:20 New Replies Which alloys do you prefer? Started by pop80_uk, 30
>   Jul 2011 1 2 18 replies 243 views Which alloys do you prefer? - last
>   post by Alec M Alec M Yesterday, 08:30 New Replies Spongey
>   Breaks!?!?!? Started by Suicida1 Zombie, 07 Feb 2013 12 replies 98
>   views Spongey Breaks!?!?!? - last post by teeman teeman 18 Feb 2013
>   New Replies Is it difficult to replace calipers? Started by Tommobug,
>   17 Feb 2013 2 replies 41 views Is it difficult to replace calipers? -
>   last post by Tommobug Tommobug 17 Feb 2013 New Replies Black RS2000
>   Wheels Started by nated84, 17 Feb 2013 1 reply 25 views Black RS2000
>   Wheels - last post by STinger STinger 17 Feb 2013 New Replies wheel
>   nuts Started by _Taylor, 17 Feb 2013 1 reply 10 views wheel nuts -
>   last post by sme101 sme101 17 Feb 2013 New Replies escort cossie
>   wheels Started by mikeszetec, 16 Feb 2013 escort cossie wheels on fez
>   1 reply 29 views escort cossie wheels - last post by STinger STinger
>   16 Feb 2013 New Replies I'm in need of a new ST500 BLACK Alloy Started
>   by MonsterST, 16 Feb 2013 1 reply 23 views I'm in need of a new ST500
>   BLACK Alloy - last post by junglistjames junglistjames 16 Feb 2013 New
>   Replies 300mm brake upgrade Started by teeman, 03 Feb 2013 12 replies
>   163 views 300mm brake upgrade - last post by teeman teeman 16 Feb 2013
>   New Replies michelin ps3 wet grip Started by kestercook, 11 Feb 2013
>   michelin, ps3 5 replies 87 views michelin ps3 wet grip - last post by
>   roballan roballan 14 Feb 2013 You posted in this topic Rear Braided
>   Hoses Issue Started by mynameisdonald, 09 Feb 2013 13 replies 124
>   views Rear Braided Hoses Issue - last post by I9 Conrad 9I I9 Conrad
>   9I 14 Feb 2013 New Replies kumho tyres Started by harryjones scfc, 12
>   Feb 2013 9 replies 55 views kumho tyres - last post by teeman teeman
>   13 Feb 2013 New Replies Braking noise Started by Kane-st, 13 Feb 2013
>   2 replies 28 views Braking noise - last post by Kane-st Kane-st 13 Feb
>   2013 Load more topics Page 1 of 172 1 2 3 Next » Start New Topic This
>   forum led by Administrator, Club Staff Community Forum Software by
>   IP.BoardLicensed to: FiestaSTOC.com - Club Network Limited - No.
>   7955718 Add us on Facebook Follow us on Twitter Watch us on Youtube
>   Subscribe to our RSS Feed RSS Feed Change Theme Mark Community Read
>   Contact Us Privacy Policy Help Time Now: Feb 20 2013 13:13 Last Visit:
>   Feb 18 2013 22:11 Exec. Time: 0.3303 Load: -- Queries: 15 queries
>   Gzip: GZIP Enabled &language=plain&expire=never

This is fine, that's what I want. But when looking at console log at what my php echo's, I'm losing alot of my data.

**php file**

```
$note       =  mysql_escape_string($_POST['note']);
echo $note;
```

**console.log response**

> \nLogo\n\n    mynameisdonald%s\'s Photo\n    mynameisdonald  \n     \n
>   \n    Sign Out\n\n      \n    Forums\n    Garage\n    Club Shop\n
>   Classifieds\n    Systems\n    My-STOC\n    Club\n\nAdvanced This
>   forum\n\n    Fiesta ST Owners Club\n    → Fiesta ST Mk6 Technical
>   Handbook\n    → Brakes, Wheels

As you can see by just echoing my text, I've lost a heck of alot of it. Could someone help me?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: it appears that the `&` in "Brakes, Wheels & Tyres" is not being escaped before posting.

Comment: The data is not properly encoded. You have `&` characters within the content, causing the key/value pattern to break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't send it as a string, send it as an object:

```
  dataObj = {
                    var1: "hello",
                    var2: 1
            };
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: YOUR_SERVER_URL,
            data: dataObj,
            success: function(data) {
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After word Wheels in url param "note" you have "&" which define new params

Answer (score 0):

You've got to escape your characters : your `&` character is interpreted as a delimiter for another key by the POST.

Try `encodeURIComponent(string input);` to escape those.

Example : `encodeURIComponent($("input[name=foo"]").val().toString());`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to send your form and avoid encoding problems in jQuery is to use [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

In you ajax call:

```
data: $("form").serialize(),
```